# Manually set y-axis min and max value and zoom-in behaviour in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zooming

I want to know the rounded min and max value that Highcharts will set on each axis before those are rendered out given minValue, maxValue and tickAmount.

My current solution is to manually calculate tickPositions so that it will show exactly what I set. So in a way, I know the values of them beforehand. The problem with this is when I zoom in, no new ticks for the zoomed-in interface are added. The reason for this is because the tickPositions attribute has blocked it from adding new ticks.

I have two questions:

- Is there any method provided by Highcharts does the min and max value? So that I can get those beforehand.
- Or is there an algorithm that Highcharts follow to calculate those value? I will implement that algorithm again to get those values?
- Or is there a way to manually implement the adding-new-ticks behaviour by myself? This is for using tickPositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tickPositioner` function to define your own logic to draw ticks:

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
        if (this.chart.resetZoomButton) { // zoomed chart
            return [1, 7]
        }

        return [1, 3, 5, 7]
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s8Ldhfcy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out.